# How to get the first element of a tuple in an array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, tuples

I have an array with some tuples inside. How do I get the first item of that tuple inside the array?

```
let cars = [("cars","cycles"),("stairs","escalator"),("table","chair")]
```

I want to get the first item in each tuples
result should be "cars", "stairs", "table"

Answer (score 22):

To get the first item at a specific index in the array you can use

```
let i = 1
cars[i].0
```

To get a `[String]` containing the first items you can do this

```
cars.map { $0.0 }
```

---

**Edit**

You can loop over the elements a couple ways.

```
let firstItems = cars.map { $0.0 }
for item in firstItems {
    print(item)
}
```

or

```
for (first, second) in cars {
    print(first)
}
```

Comment: That is actually an elegant solution

Comment: Thank you very much for the input, but i wanted to loop the the elements because these tuples will increase and i will not know how many items there will be in the array.

Comment: The map function works by iterating over each element and "mapping" it to a new array, so it will work over an arbitrary number of tuples in the array.  It "maps" an array element consisting of a tuple to an array element consisting of the first element of a tuple.

Answer (score 1):

You can access each tuple by element number.
let result = [cars[0].0, cars[1].0, cars[2].0]

Comment: Thank you very much for the input, but i wanted to loop the the elements because these tuples will increase and i will not know how many items there will be in the array.